# JTidy: how to process specific tag

Tags: html, xhtml, jtidy

I'm processing bad-formated HTML pages with JTidy. I am only interested in fixing a specific set of tags, for example `<img> <table>`. Is there anyway to tell JTidy to focus on only those tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not (or at least not that I know).

But what is wrong with getting the full document corrected?

(TIP: JTidy might not be the best solution for cleaning HTML, there are others, like: http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/ which might give better result(s) in your case, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009897/recommend-an-alternative-to-jtidy)